# Workaround for stack limit in windows with gnu g++

Tags: c++, gnu

I have built and compiled a command line program with GNU g++ which "overflows" the stack for a number of reasons, mainly deep inheritance, lots of objects created, etc. So I followed this workaround on Mac OS X to solve the problem when linking:

```
-Wl,-stack_size,0x10000000,-stack_addr,0xc0000000
```

Under Linux, I just tried `ulimit -s unlimited`; running the program in this way does not give a segmentation fault any more

But when trying to compile it on Windows with GNU g++, the compiler does not recognize

```
-Wl,-stack_size,0x10000000,-stack_addr,0xc0000000
```

What other option would you use as a workaround for the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure "manly deep heritage" would be part of this problem . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[-Wl,--stack,*somelargesize*](http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html) looks like what you're after. However, I'd strongly recommend refactoring your code to make use of the heap for large allocations instead. Address space is a finite resource and your "workaround" asks for quite a large chunk of it.

Comment: @Andy: but its size doesn't default to a fixed 2Mb and he doesn't have to ask for 256Mb of it up front in order to get his application to fit; the C library is pretty good at managing large allocations for him.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) suggests that you might want to try the following command line option (search for -fno-stack-limit):

```
-fno-stack-limit
```

If that fails on its own, then [this other page](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2000-05/msg00598.html) suggests to also add:

```
-fstack-check
```

Comment: Hi!

I tried these options with the IDE DEV-C++ (from bloodshed) but I still get stack overflow, any hints?

Comment: This answer is wrong. This option "generates code to ensure that the stack does not grow beyond a certain value"; it is merely a check to let the program fail if the stack grows too large.